# ALERT ,when searched word not found in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

my coding is all about

1)fetch the data from mysql thro php

2)get data from php to d3 based on input by using  PHP URL
I want to set alert when the text in the input field is not found in mysql database..

now when I try with the word other than mysql data, it shows

**this console**

[image]

how can i alert when wrong word(other than mysql database value) is submitted

**HTML FORM**

```
      <form name="editorForm"> 
      <input type="text"name="editor"  id="editor" 
      onchange="document.getElementById('editorForm').submit();">
      <input type="submit"value="butn">
      </form>
```

**JQUERY TO FETCH THE DATA FROM PHP BASED ON URL**

```
       $(function () {
       $('form').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var t=$('form').serialize();
       var u='http://localhost:8888/saff/indexi.php?'+t;
       if(u==null){
        alert("not found");
        }
        else{           
        funn();
         }
```

**D3 CODES**

```
        function funn(){
         d3.json(u, function(treeData) {
           //D3 CODES
             });
              }
```

**my php code**

```
            <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","data");       

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())                
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
               $name=$_GET['editor'];
             $sql="SELECT * FROM phptab where value LIKE '%".$name."%'";
            $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    $data = array();

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                      $data[] = $row;
                    }

             function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
            {
                foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
                {
                    if($row['parent'] == $parent_id)
                    {
                        foreach($row as $k => $v)
                            $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
                        unset($src_arr[$idx]);
            $tree[$row['id']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
                    }
                }
                ksort($tree);
                return $tree;
            }

            function insertIntoNestedArray(&$array, $searchItem){

                if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
                    array_push($array, $searchItem);
                    return;
                }
                if(empty($array)){ return; }
             array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
                if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
                        array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
                        return;
                    }
                    insertIntoNestedArray($item['children'], $searchItem);
            }, $searchItem);
            }
            $nestedArray = array();
            foreach($data as $itemData){
             //$nestedArrayItem['value'] = $itemData['value'];
              $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
                $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
              $nestedArrayItem['tooltip'] = $itemData['tooltip'];
                 $nestedArrayItem['color'] = $itemData['color'];
                 $nestedArrayItem['level'] = $itemData['level'];

                $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();
            //$data[]=$dat;
                insertIntoNestedArray($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
            }
            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            $json= json_encode($nestedArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            echo $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
               ?>
```

works as expected when the word used is exist in the database
and the [page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxR6w.png)
 getting correct json format in the mozilla console.but design is not shown in the page...but in chrome ,everything works fine..

Comment: wait what? fetch data from the url  `var u='http://localhost:8888/saff/indexi.php?'+t;`? did you heard of ajax?

Comment: yes.why anything wrong in using this url to fetch data

Comment: when i  type the word in the input field which is in database ..it fetch the data correctly ,no problem there ...when i type the word which is not in the database it shows  Unexpected end of JSON input in console...but i want to alert"not found"..

Comment: What comes back from the Server, check **Network** tab in the Browser console, there you can see if vaild json is returned or not.

Comment: getting correct json format in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test if the page is empty in the json function of the d3

```
 function funn(){
         d3.json(u, function(treeData) {
            if(!treeData.length){
              alert("not found");
            }else {
           //D3 CODES
            }
           });
          }
```

Make sure that you return a empty object from the page when not found